# Not able to call pg_advisory_lock function in Postgres using jooq

Tags: java, jooq

I'm trying to call the administrative function `pg_catalog.pg_advisory_unlock` using JOOQ. I'm able to generate a model for that function by having this in my gradle build file:

```
schemata {
    schema {
        inputSchema = "public"
    }
    schema {
        inputSchema = "pg_catalog"
    }
    includes = "public.*|pg_catalog.pg_advisory_lock"
}
```

The file `pg_catalog>Routines.java` has a method public `static void pgAdvisoryLock1(Configuration configuration, Long __1)` which I call as such:

```
Connection connection = DatabaseService.getInstance().getConnection("sampleUser");
    Settings settings = new Settings()
        .withRenderMapping(new RenderMapping()
            .withSchemata(
                new MappedSchema().withInput("shard_0")
                    .withOutput("shard_1")));
    DSLContext create = DSL.using(connection, settings);

    Long param = 1l;
    pgAdvisoryLock1(create.configuration(), param);
```

I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [select * from "pg_catalog"."pg_advisory_lock"("_1" := ?)]; ERROR: function pg_catalog.pg_advisory_lock(_1 => bigint) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Would appreciate any help. Thanks!

EDIT: Thinking about it a bit more, I think I remember reading somewhere that JOOQ had issues with non named parameters in postgres functions. Wondering if this is related to that. Since it's an administrative inbuilt function, I wouldn't be able to change the non named parameter to a named parameter. I'm using version 3.6.2 of JOOQ (mainly cause I'm using this gradle plugin (https://github.com/etiennestuder/gradle-jooq-plugin) which is using that version of JOOQ I think. Not sure if newer versions of JOOQ has that fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, this issue has been fixed in the meantime.

- jOOQ 3.8.0: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4920

The hard-wired dependency in this plugin towards a specific jOOQ version is a known issue (https://github.com/etiennestuder/gradle-jooq-plugin/pull/14), which I'm hoping is going to be fixed soon.

Comment: Thanks Lukas, I appreciate it!